# No shadowing in Python when using with-statement?

Tags: python, python-2.7, scope

Consider the following Python code:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
    def __enter__(self):
        return self
    def __exit__(self,type,value,trace):
        return True

t = Test("a")
with Test("b") as t:
    print t.name
print t.name
```

I would have expected the output to be *b,a*, but it actually is *b,b*.

Is there no such thing as *shadowing* in Python? Is this really expected behavior?

Comment: The variables used in `with` statement are not cleaned up, so you've no reference to `Test("a")` now, hence it prints b, b.

Comment: No, Python's scoping rules do not allow for shadowing. You have local, closure and global scopes *only*.

Comment: As such, the `with .. as` binding is local to the current scope, exactly the same way that `for ... in ` binds locally, not just for the `for` suite.